# Can I increase my medi-gel capacity?

Tags: mass-effect-3

How can I increase the amount of medi-gels I can carry? I seem to be wasting a lot of them by picking them up for just some minor experience.

Comment: Interestingly, I upgrade my capacity by 1 and then stopped since I would much rather all that experience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can purchase additional medi-gel capacity from the Siirta Foundation kiosk in Huerta Memorial Hospital.

There are 5 ranks, of increasing price available. Each gives +1 to total medigel.

Comment: So, max of 8, right?

Comment: You can also get a +1 to capacity as a quest reward.